# Calculate approximate distance between two points

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to calculate approximate distance between two points with respect to road map on Google Maps. 75% of the time the points are not on a straight line, and they form a triangle on the road map. I am taking right angle as well as obtuse angle into consideration. And the line created by the points to be the hypotenuse.

Lets take the line formed by the points: "x"
Other Two lines: "y" & "z"
Assuming y and z equal

Now I am taking two options as stated earlier for best result:

Option 1:

```
y = x(sin 45)/(sin90)
Total Distance = 2y
```

Option 2:

```
y = x(sin 30)/(sin120)
Total Distance = 2y
```

On calculation the distance by getting the all the coordinates of the distance. It is different from both at and approximately 10 to 20%.

In almost all cases the second one provides the best value on checking with the Google Maps vehicle distance.

Is there any better alternative for maximum accuracy?

Comment: Do you meant that you have a path that has multiple points along it and you need the distance from one end to the other? Why not get the distance between each set of points and ignore the angles? If you want the actual straight line distance from one end of the path to the other, throw out all of the points between the ends and calculate the distance using the end point coordinates. Can you point to an example page that shows the type of lines and points that you are using? I wrote some code to figure out distance traveled for a route with many points. I will post the code if that is what you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Haversine formula?

which is:

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
  dlat = lat2 - lat1
  a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)) 
  d = R * c
```